# How to get category name from URL and pass to a template

Tags: categories

I'm using the following page template to display the posts in a single category and plan to format the first post differently than the others.  This works as desired but I have the category_name hard coded in the template.  I want to use this template for several different categories and would like to learn how to pass the category_name to the template from a link.

For example, the link to the desired page using the special template is http://wildcatweb.net/5th/ and '5th' is also the category_name.  How do I tell the template to get the category_name from the URL and use it in the template?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: pageAssignments
*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="small-12 large-8 columns" id="content" role="main">
<header>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            </header>

  <!-- show latest post FULL -->

 <?php query_posts('showposts=1&category_name=5th'); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="lastest-post">



     <h2 class="pagetitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

</div><!--close .latest-post -->

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?><!-- end lastest post -->

 <!-- show older post excerpts -->

<?php query_posts('showposts=5&offset=1&category_name=5th'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="older-post">

         <h3 class="pagetitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"     rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        </div><!--.older-post -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?><!-- end past-entry -->

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating pages and assigning a template, I would use the `category_template` filter to load a specific template for all those particular categories. In this example I use a hardcoded array, but this could be adapted to load an option which stores the category slugs you want the template applied to.

```
function wpa_category_template( $templates = '' ){
    $special_categories = array(
        'one',
        'another',
        'more'
    );
    $this_category = get_queried_object();
    if( in_array( $this_category->slug, $special_categories ) ){
        $templates = locate_template( array( 'special_category.php', $templates ), false );
    }   
    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'wpa_category_template' );
```

You then no longer have to query for these posts in the template, as the posts are already in the main query. (also, as an aside, [never use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) ).

Within the template you can use [`single_cat_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title) to output the name.

You also don't have to use two queries and loops to style the first post differently, just check the `current_post` var in the loop to know what post you're currently outputting.

```
if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();

        if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post ):
            echo 'this is the first post';
        else:
            echo 'this is post > 1';
        endif;

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Milo, thank you for your help.  Your concise solution was perfect and much simpler than my first attempt.  I'm quickly learning a lot about Wordpress and your reply was exactly what I needed.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will use the first Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory from the following list:

1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

You can add the category name by adding this code to the template before The Loop:

```
<p>Category: <?php single_cat_title(); ?></p>
```

Comment: I don't want this template to apply to all category pages, only the 5-6 that need special formatting. That is why I'm creating a different template.  Outside of duplicating the template for each category-ID or category-slug do have an idea how I could pass the category name to the template?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Updated my answer with the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use this template for multiple categories, presumably you have named it `category.php`?

To get the name of the Term that is currently being displayed, use this (before you enter The Loop) -

```
$taxonomy_slug = $wp_query->tax_query->queries[0]['taxonomy'];
$term_slug = $wp_query->tax_query->queries[0]['terms'][0];
$term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy_slug);
$term_name = $term->name;
```

And then replace -

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

With -

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $term_name ?></h1>
```

Comment: I didn't name the file category.php because I only want to use it for a few category since I am planning to add some special formatting for only 5-6 pages only.  Thanks for showing me how to echo the query.  I think that will be helpful for a variety of things.  Will look at it more when I have a chance later today.